# How to fix an error in setup Cypress Component Testing

Tags: testing, compiler-errors, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I wanted to implement component testing in CRA, but I get an error during configuration:

```
Your configFile threw an error from: cypress/config/myConfig.config.ts

We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed.

../../Library/Caches/Cypress/12.12.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/helpers/createReactAppHandler.js:70:15
  68 |     }
  69 |     catch (err) {
> 70 |         throw new Error(`Failed to require webpack config at ${webpackConfigPath} with error: ${err}`);
     |               ^
  71 |     }
  72 | }
  73 | exports.cypressGlobals = ['cy', 'Cypress', 'before', 'after', 'context'];
  74 | function addCypressToWebpackEslintRulesInPlace(webpackConfig) {
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N53M6.png)

Cypress 12.12.0

I have reinstalled Cypress and I keep getting the same error.
Has anyone had a similar error?

Answer (score 1):

The package `@cypress/webpack-dev-server` which you are using in your config is looking for the file `<project-root>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`.

It looks like you have used the `eject` script which removes the `<project-root>/node_modules/react-scripts` folder completely.

If you wish to stay ejected, you can add `webpack.config.js` to the project root instead.

This is the relevant piece of code (from `@cypress/webpack-dev-server`):

```js
webpackConfigPath = require.resolve('react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js', {
  paths: [devServerConfig.cypressConfig.projectRoot],
})
```

When `require.resolve('react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js')` fails (after eject) the path at `devServerConfig.cypressConfig.projectRoot` is used -  which is just the project folder if you aren't using a mono-repo.